# Converting 32 byte array to 32 bit string

Tags: java

I have the following code. I have a 32 length string which is converted to a byte array. Problem is I need to convert it to a 32 length string. Problem is, it's coming back as a 64 length string. Is there some magic I should look at?

```
class Go {

    public void run() {
        String testString = "12345678901234567890123456789012";

        byte[] bytesData = testString.getBytes();
        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();

        for (byte b : bytesData) {
            st.append(String.format("%2d", b));
        }

        System.out.println(st.toString());
    }


    public static void main(String[] v2) {
        Go v = new Go();
        v.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be here?

Comment: If you want to encode text to bytes, choose a specific character encoding. The one you get from `String.getBytes()` is unknown to you since it varies across systems, users and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@azro gave you the right answer, but for the sake of education, I'll point out what you were doing wrong. When you get the `byte` value of a `char` in a string, you're getting the ascii value. So when you use `String.format("%2d", b)`, you're getting the `int` value of the `char` itself, not the `char` that it represents. Instead, you could change your loop to something like this:

```
    for (byte b : bytesData) {
        st.append( (char)b );
    }
```

But again, use what @azro said. I'm only explaining how you could go about it if you were interested in how things work under the hood.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I was looking for. The actual issue was something deeper, but your "tutorial" helped me find the solution.

Comment: No, not ASCII. You are taking the value of a byte—which in the case of `testString.getBytes()` is a character code using the user's Java's system character encoding—and casting it as a UTF-16 code unit. You could argue that there are some values for which this would arrive at the expected result but conceptually—between the answer _and_ the question—it's all wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You use this `String` constructor : `public String(byte[] bytes)` ([*Oracle Doc*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-))

```
String testString = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
System.out.println(testString);                          //12345678901234567890123456789012

byte[] bytesData = testString.getBytes();

String res = new String(bytesData);
System.out.println(res);                                 //12345678901234567890123456789012
```